# How to restart explorer like taskmgr?

Tags: windows, explorer, taskmanager

When you select the explorer process in taskmgr, the button will be "restart" instead of "end task/end process". After clicking restart, explorer shows in "windows process" in taskmgr again as before, but "kill&start" will not. Then I have some questions:

1. How can I restart explorer like taskmgr?
2. How could taskmgr know explorer can be restarted and restart it?
3. Can I make a app that tells taskmgr it can be restarted?

[screenshoot: explorer's position in taskmgr, before and after restart, not there after kill&start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSMjh.png)

My current code for kill&start explorer (C#)

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (p.ProcessName.ToUpper().Contains("EXPLORER"))
    {
        p.Kill();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
}
Process.Start("explorer.exe");
```

And I tried to use cmd

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
explorer
```

Comment: Please add screenshots and a better explanation of what you mean. You mean that when you right-click Explorer in the Processes tab of the Task Manager, you get a unique menu option named "Restart". When you click that, the Explorer is restarted. But it doesn't reopen any Explorer _windows_ you had open. You claim it does, but no-repro here. Also, what does happen when you run the code you show?

Comment: @CodeCaster I didn't claim it does. It does "reopen" the desktop though.

Comment: AFAIK the shell process of the current user gets restarted automatically by the system when it notices it was killed, so I suspect they just changed the label of the end process menu entry without any actual code change in task manager; IOW, probably terminating it suffices to trigger an automatic restart. The different menu text is probably either hard-coded in task manager, or it looks up what the shell executable is for the current user.